# Easy way to prove $|\text{curl}\ \mathbf n|^2=(\mathbf n\cdot \text{curl}\ \mathbf n)^2+|\mathbf n \wedge\text{curl}\ \mathbf n|^2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, physics, vector-analysis

Let $\mathbf n$ be a unit vector field. I would like to show that
$$|\text{curl}\ \mathbf n|^2=(\mathbf n\cdot \text{curl}\ \mathbf n)^2+|\mathbf n \wedge\text{curl}\ \mathbf n|^2$$
holds.

Expanding in coordinate is straightforward but looks ugly and doesn't provide much insight. Could anyone provide a better proof of this based on some properties of curl?

Comment: It just looks to me like the Pythagorean Theorem: the first part of the sum is the component of curl $\overline{n}$ through the $\overline{n}$ direction, while the second part is the component through the orthogonal direction of $\overline{n}$.

Comment: If [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotacional#Identidades) are right, curl has the next propery: $$ n\times \nabla\times F=\nabla_F(n\cdot F),$$ where the notation $\nabla_F$ means that gradient operator acts only over $F$. Apply this property two your second term on the right-hand, it turns out to be $$\|\nabla(n\cdot n)\|=\| \nabla(\|n\|^2)\|=\|\nabla(1)\|=\|0\|=0, $$ since the vector has unit length.

Comment: @Klaramun That makes sense, I overlooked the fact that the 2nd term is orthogonal. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any properties of curl - for any vectors $u,v$ [we have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Alternative_formulation) $|u|^2|v|^2 = (u \cdot v)^2 + |u \wedge v|^2,$ so your formula follows from the fact that $|n|=1.$

Comment: Yeah I feel stupid now. The presence of curl made me overlooked such simple fact.